# Creating a variable with month number from existing variable with the DATETIME18. informat in SAS

Tags: function, sas, informat

I am trying to something very simple but failing miserably.

Using the SAS query builder I want to create a new variable with the month number, based on an existing date variable.

An example of my variable I want to change is this:
07/01/2015 00:00

So I want to create a new variable with the number 1 in it.

My existing variable has an informat DATETIME18.

So I have tried the following:

```
month(t1.My_Date)
month(t1.My_Date, 'DATETIME18.')
```

Both of the above create a new variable but all the fields are empty.

So I thought to change the variables informat to remove the time element & then use the month function, so I tried:

```
MDY(t1.Issue_Date, 'DATETIME18.', 'DATEw.')
```

But I get the following errors:
ERROR: Function MDY requires a numeric expression as argument 2.
ERROR: Function MDY requires a numeric expression as argument 3.

Any ideas?  I basically want to pull out the month number from a variable when the variable has the DATETIME18. informat.

Thanks in advance
Paul

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation?  `mdy()` has nothing to do with the format...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable is datetime and `month()` function works with dates. Use `datepart()` function before using `month()`:

```
month(datepart(t1.My_Date))
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was  hoping for & worked a treat.  :)